# Executing stdout results line by line that has a prompt confirmation

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, xargs, expect

I have a command that (potentially) prints several lines and then I want to execute them one by one (using `xargs` for example, or anything else):

```
find . -name "*string*" -print | awk '{ print "echo " $1 " >> file.txt" }' | xargs -L 1
```

Execution of each of the `echo ... >> file.txt` commands will give a prompt `Enter a value:` where the user has to explicitly type `yes` for confirmation or `no` to cancel further execution of the command.

Is it possible to pipe this into one line to always enter `yes` for example? Or halt until user enters yes?

So far I'm thinking of 2 possible solutions:

1. Using expect script.
2. Capturing stdout of the executed command line by line, and looping over
   those lines until I reach the prompt, then either waiting for user
   input or adding `yes` or `no` automatically.

Is there an easier way to do this and piping an extra command after `xargs`? (Let say if I always want to enter `yes`?).
Which of the above solutions would be better. I would assume the second one would be preferable to ensure cross-platform compatibility and avoiding external dependencies like `expect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the pathname of all files whose names contain the string `string` to a file `file.txt`, with confirmation for each one.

This is how you do that with `find`:

```
find . -name '*string*' -ok printf '%s\n' {} \; >>file.txt
```

The `-ok` option will execute the given utility with the found pathname inserted in place of `{}` if the user replies `y` (or `yes`).  The `find` command will wait until a reply is given.

To *always* reply `y`, use

```
yes | find ... >>file.txt
```

(or change `-ok` to `-exec`).

To always reply `n`, use

```
yes n | find ... >>file.txt
```

---

Note that your original command is unsafe as it creates code which includes filenames as-is.  A specially crafted filename could therefore possibly be used to create code to execute something not meant to be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the input and for the warning :) I'll try it out and see how this can be modified.